# Printing not working properly in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython, python-zip

I was in Jupyter Notebook playing around with the `zip` function in Python, when I noticed a print statement wasn't printing. This is the code contained in the cell:

```
z1=["a","b","c"]
z2=[1,2,3]
collect=zip(z1,z2)

print(list(collect))

for index,(item1,item2) in enumerate(collect):
    print(f"{index} corresponding to {item1} and {item2}")
```

And this code outputs

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

Jupyter completely ignores the print statement in the for loop!

**However, I noticed that if I comment out the first print statement, the print statements in the for loop then print.** So, if the code in the cell is

```
z1=["a","b","c"]
z2=[1,2,3]
collect=zip(z1,z2)

#print(list(collect))

for index,(item1,item2) in enumerate(collect):
    print(f"{index} corresponding to {item1} and {item2}")
```

then the output becomes

```
0 corresponding to a and 1 
1 corresponding to b and 2 
2 corresponding to c and 3
```

Something also very peculiar, is that if I change the print statement in the cell to something else, say `print(collect)`, both print statements then print. I.e. if I change the code to

```
z1=["a","b","c"]
z2=[1,2,3]
collect=zip(z1,z2)

print(collect)

for index,(item1,item2) in enumerate(collect):
    print(f"{index} corresponding to {item1} and {item2}")
```

the output becomes

```
<zip object at 0x7fadf85db0c0>
0 corresponding to a and 1 
1 corresponding to b and 2 
2 corresponding to c and 3
```

This is super weird!!! I am just wondering if anyone knows why this is happening, or how to fix it? I've been having a few problems with printing in Jupyter Notebook to be honest. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Jupyter Notebook, actually, but rather with what `zip` returns.

`zip` returns an iterator object. Once you exhaust it (for example, by creating a list from all of its elements), it is empty and iterating over it is equivalent to iterating over empty collection.

That's why printing `list(collect)` prevents it from working, while anything else will work just fine.
You can easily see that by repeating that print statement:

```
z1=["a","b","c"]
z2=[1,2,3]
collect=zip(z1,z2)

print(list(collect)) # [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
print(list(collect)) # []
```